How can I emerge two tables in SQL Database Using IF Statement
In my SQL Database, I have a table "TRANSFER" and columns with "amount_cr" and "amount_db." In my PHP Code, I have a PHP file that sends a report in the figure to $amount_cr while another file sends to $amount_db. I need a situation where a table shows the two columns using an IF Statement. That is when $amount_cr is input, let $amount_db remain blank, and vice versa.
<tr>
<th scope="col">AMOUNT CR</th>
<th scope="col">AMOUNT DB</th> 
</tr> 
<?php 
$cs_id = $_SESSION['cs_id']; 
$his = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE cs_id = '$cs_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3"); 
$his->execute(array(":cs_uname" => $_SESSION['cs_uname'])); 
while($rows = $his->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
?> 

// I tried the following as a newbie
<tr> 
<td style="color:green;" scope="row">+ $ <?php echo $rows['amount_cr']; ?></td>
<td style="color:red;" scope="row">- $<?php echo $rows['amount_db']; ?></td>
</tr>

This is what I get as the output enter image description here
I wish to have the output this way enter image description here
Amount (Credit) | Amount (Debit)
When the incoming input is for amount_cr, it appears on the amount_cr column while amount_db remain blank, vice versa. Like what I have on the Image

PHP like most languages has a concept of if statements. These are program flow control structures. You can use an if statement to conditionally display the value.

Did you make a mistake here '$cs_id'? It should be :cs_uname or something like that

Added if, else condition inside while loop to display blank space when value is 0 for credit or debit.
   <tr>
  <th scope="col">AMOUNT CR</th>
  <th scope="col">AMOUNT DB</th>
</tr> 

<?php 
$cs_id = $_SESSION['cs_id']; 
$his = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE cs_id = :cs_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3"); 
$his->execute(array(":cs_id" => $cs_id)); // Changed to use prepared statement for cs_id

while($rows = $his->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?> 

<tr> 
  <!-- Display amount_cr if it exists -->
  <td style="color:green;" scope="row">
    <?php 
      if (!empty($rows['amount_cr'])) {
        echo "+ $ " . $rows['amount_cr']; 
      } else {
        echo "-"; // Blank if no amount_cr value
      }
    ?>
  </td>
  
  <!-- Display amount_db if it exists -->
  <td style="color:red;" scope="row">
    <?php 
      if (!empty($rows['amount_db'])) {
        echo "- $ " . $rows['amount_db']; 
      } else {
        echo "-"; // Blank if no amount_db value
      }
    ?>
  </td>
</tr>

<?php 
}
?>


Thanks so much. It worked Pefectly for me.
